# data = null on snapshot in stream builder

Tags: flutter, dart

Im trying to connect my viewmodel to my screen using streams for the first time but im struggling to grasp the concept completely.

My Screen:

```
class LoginAndSignupScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  LoginAndSignupScreen({@required this.viewModel});

  final LoginAndSignupScreenViewModelType viewModel;

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => new _LoginAndSignupScreenState();
}

class _LoginAndSignupScreenState extends State<LoginAndSignupScreen> {
  Widget showErrorMessage() {
    return StreamBuilder<String>(
      initialData: "",
      stream: widget.viewModel.errorText,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
          return new Text(
            snapshot.data,
            style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 13.0,
                color: Colors.red,
                height: 1.0,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w300
            ),
          );
        }
    );
  }
```

My view model:

```
abstract class LoginAndSignupScreenViewModelType {
  Stream<String> get errorText;

  void signIn(String email, String password);
  void signUp(String email, String password, String firstName, String lastName);
}

class LoginAndSignupScreenViewModel implements LoginAndSignupScreenViewModelType {
  LoginAndSignupScreenViewModel({@required this.authenticationService,
                                 @required this.cloudStoreService});

  final AuthenticationServiceType authenticationService;
  final CloudStoreServiceType cloudStoreService;

  final errorController = StreamController<String>.broadcast();

  @override
  Stream<String> get errorText => errorController.stream;

  @override
  void signIn(String email, String password) async {
    try {
      String userId = await authenticationService.signIn(email, password);
      User user = await cloudStoreService.fetchUserWithId(userId)
        .whenComplete(loginCallback);
      print('Signed in: ${user.firstName} ${user.lastName}');
    } catch (error) {
      errorController.add(error);
    }
  }

  @override 
  void signUp(String email, String password, String firstName, String lastName) async {
    try {
      String userId = await authenticationService.signUp(email, password);
      User user = new User(userId, firstName, lastName);
      await cloudStoreService.createUser(user)
        .then(showHomeScreenIfValidUser);
      print('Signed up user: ${user.id}');
    } catch (error) {
        errorController.add(error);
    }
  }
}
```

When I do this and run I get an error saying that `snapshot.data = null` which I understand. My issue is I want there to be no widget if there is no error string.

Can anyone help?

Comment: I don't see where you're using `snapshot.data`...

Comment: @Benjamin sorry, have update the `_LoginAndSignupScreenState`

Comment: If you don't want the widget to appear, use the `Visibility` widget and you can set it to not show the widget depending on a condition. In your case, I'm assuming it would be whether the data is null.

Comment: Actually @Benjamin Visibity didn't work for me if the snapshot.data was null it still failed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question, different widgets can be returned depending on the value of `snapshot.data`:

```dart
stream: widget.viewModel.errorText,
builder: (context, snapshot) {
  if (snapshot.hasData) {
    return Text(
      snapshot.data,
      style: TextStyle(
          fontSize: 13.0,
          color: Colors.red,
          height: 1.0,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.w300
      ),
    );
  }

  // returns an invisible widget
  return SizedBox.shrink();

}
```

That aside, did you know that you can have a `Stream` that yields both data and errors? I wonder why you are using callbacks instead of just one stream for everything, where `snapshot.data` has data, and `snapshot.error` has errors.

Comment: Thanks! i didnt know it had error know but i probably should have guessed. I dont quite follow what you mean in how to implement with one stream though.

Comment: Instead of having an `errorText` stream you could simply have a more general `Stream<User>` and yield both data (`User`) and errors. Using a `StreamController` this would mean calling `add` for data and `addError` to add exceptions.

Comment: Good luck! If you need inspiration, Firebase Auth does something similar. Maybe this video can help: https://fireship.io/lessons/advanced-flutter-firebase/